# Unity can not Build on Android:java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: already added: Manifest$permission (UNEXPECTED TOP-LEVEL EXCEPTION)

Tags: android, unity-game-engine

1. When I have

   ----Plugins/Android/{res, jar….}

   ----Plugins/Android/AndroidManifest.xml

   It's OK
2. When I have Facebook and Google+

   ----Plugins/Android/{res, jar….}

   ----Plugins/Android/facebookSDK folder

   ----Plugins/Android/google-play-services_lib  (google+)

   ----Plugins/Android/BaseGameUtils  (google+)

   ----Plugins/Android/MainLibProj  (google+)

   ----Plugins/Android/AndroidManifest.xml

   Can not Build to Android, getting error:

> UNEXPECTED TOP-LEVEL EXCEPTION: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException:
>   already added: L …. /Manifest$permission;

It's because of this line on AndroidManifest.xml

> ```
>      <permission android:name="{my package}.permission.C2D_MESSAGE"
>      android:protectionLevel="signature" />
> ```

When I remove this permission, I can build and run, but can not get Push Notification (lack of permission).

Question: How can I keep this permission on Unity?

Comment: I am running into the same issue. Were you able to figure out a solution to this problem?  Thanks so much!

Comment: Yes, I solved this issue. When you build your ----Plugins/Android/{ jar….}. Don't add any permission on AndroidManifest. And then add that permission on ----Plugins/Android/AndroidManifest.xml. Good luck!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Finally, I solved this issue.

When you build your ----Plugins/Android/{ jar….} (your own project). Don't add any permission on AndroidManifest.

And then add that permission on ----Plugins/Android/AndroidManifest.xml. Good luck!